# ng build --prod builds an outdated version of the application

Tags: angular-cli

I'm finishing up my Angular application and trying to deploy it. In the past, I've always used 'ng serve' to run the app. It has, and continues, to work perfectly fine. When I use ng build --prod, my dist folder is filled with what appears to be an extremely outdated version of the application. It is missing all of the files in my app folder. Looking at the Angular.Json file, I can see that a lot of what is being created in the dist folder is coming from it. I've wondered if I add the missing folders to the Json file if they'll get used in the build. However, this seems very unlikely to work considering how many 3rd party files (like Kendo components and css files) are within the project. 
Perhaps I am misunderstanding something.

I should add: I added "src/app" and now all my components are included, but the node_module folder that contains all my css (from bootstrap and kendo) doesn't work.

I cannot help but think there is some automatic update for the Angular.Json file that I am neglecting to use.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Views": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "pm",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/Views",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/api"
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css"
              },
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "APM:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "APM:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "APM:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css"
              },
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "APM:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "APM:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "APM"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of the files are not in the dist folder but inside the Views folder which is present in the dist folder .

"dist/Views"

You can check there.

If still not clear you can delete the dist folder all contents and just run the prod build again

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I checked in dist/Views. I've re-run the builder multiple times.

Comment: You can change the path to other folder and try it there it will create a new files only like creat a prod folder in the level of project folder and change the output path to that location and it will create a new one .  It may be old files because writing to the folder and me disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:
1. create an web.config file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="index.html" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then go into the Index.html file and change  `<base href="/"> to  <base href="./">.`